# Open text in Pages—Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my Swift 2 app, a user creates a string of text via a text field then shares it to another app. Right now, I can only make the text share as a .txt file, which doesn't provide the option to `Open In Pages` when I open the system share dialog. How can I make it so that the user has an option to open their inputted text as a document in Pages?

Must I convert the text to a .docx or .pages format? And if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to save the file locally as a .txt file and then open it using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Here is full sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    var interactionController: UIDocumentInteractionController?

    func openInPages(body: String, title: String) throws {
       // create a file path in a temporary directory
       let fileName = "\(title).txt"
       let filePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

       // save the body to the file
       try body.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

       // for iPad to work the sheet must be presented from a bar item, retrieve it here as below or create an outlet of the Export bar button item.
       let barButtonItem = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!

       // present Open In menu
       interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
       interactionController?.presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem(barButtonItem, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Call `openInPages` from anywhere in your code (like when the user presses an `Export` bar button item):

```
openInPages("This will be the body of the new document", title: "SomeTitle")
```

[image: this is the result]

Comment: Thank you very much; I tried your method (I used exactly your code except I had to call `openInPages` like so: `do {
            
        try openInPages(flowNote.text, title: "Exported from NoteFlow, Aug 1")
        } catch _ {
            print("unable to open in Pages.")
        }
` and nothing happened when calling the function (I ran this on my physical iPad air and in the iPhone 6 simulator). Many nonfatal errors appeared in the console, it looks like XCode had to break a bunch of constraints in the Airdrop menu. (?). So I need some help here!

Comment: you are probably attempting to call the method too soon in the app lifecycle. see updated code

Comment: I don't think that's it. Calling it from viewdidload like in your new code results in no error being printed but also doesn't result in the share dialog popping up at all. (Note: the broken constraint error messages still pop up in the console when calling it exactly as you do from viewdidload.)

Comment: confirmed iPad doesn't like the `presentOpenInMenuFromRect` call. it may need to call `presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem` instead. will try to get it to work, in the mean time the existing code will work on an iPhone.

Comment: Is there a way I can convert the .txt to a .docx before I call the open in menu? That would be better (it'll work with Google Docs and other apps better). Should I use the WordSDK that Brett mentioned, or is there an easier built-in way?

Comment: this is out of the scope of the current question, which was specifically asking about Pages. that being said, .docx format is not that complex, it is simply a zip file w/ embedded xml files. i would recommend avoiding a 3rd party library and spend the time to reverse engineer a "Hello World" docx file to make a template. if you open another question about this i will happily try to help

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help, @Casey. Have some internet points!