# Convert text to .docx document file and open share dialog, Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I have some text the user enters in my Swift 2 app. I need to convert it locally to a .docx file (either by modifying the text of an existing document or creating a new one) and then open up a `UIDocumentInteractionController` share dialog so the user can open this document up in Pages, Word, and Google Docs.

I am clear on how to open up a UIDocumentInteractionController, but right now I can only let the user share a .txt file; I need to let the user share a .docx file.

Comment: Your question asks how to *convert* text to docx document but the answer you've accepted still saves a text file, only with the docx *extension*. This doesn't make it a Word file. Please edit your question and explain what you really need. Thanks.

Comment: @EricAya I see your point, but the user can easily export it (via the instructions in the answer owlswipe linked to) to apps like Pages, Word, and Docs that make it a word doc. So really, it does become a word document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this one out for you.

Take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708440/5700898) user `Casey` made, and just change this line:

```
let fileName = "\(title).txt"
```

to this

```
let fileName = "\(title).docx"
```

and Swift will figure out that you want to export your text as a document, and convert it automatically.

Comment: when I share this docx file then it will not be opening on whatsapp. any suggestion?